# Unable to use vscode debugger in a Express js with typscript project

Tags: typescript, express, debugging, vscode-debugger, nodemon

Here is my package.json file

`

```
{
  "name": "crm-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"yarn tsc --watch\" \"yarn tsc-alias --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/index.js\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.10",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "tsc-alias": "^1.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  }
}
```

`

I have tried many ways in launch.json

`

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach",
      "port": 1234,
      "request": "attach",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "type": "node"
    },
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome with Debugger",
      "port": 7999,
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "chrome",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/static",
    },
    {
      "name": "Nodemon: Attach Express.js + TypeScript 2",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9229,
      "restart": true,
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/backend"
    }
  ]
}
```

`

Only "Nodemon: Attach Express.js + TypeScript" was working (for this i have to add "--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229" in package.json after where nodemon writter),
but it is catching breakpoint of output compiled "js" files not source "ts" files. (and i have to add.

Comment: Have you tried adding `sourceMap: true` to a `compilerOptions` object in your `tsconfig` file?

Comment: It working now after adding sourceMap: true. Thank you

Comment: Yes no worries! sourceMap does extanctly what it says, it maps compiled js back to TS for debugging, but you should turn it of when you build your code for prod as it would increase bundle size. Would you mind if I post my comment as an answer for you to approve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your `tsconfig` file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true
}
```

It will map compiled javascript back to typescript for debugging purposes, but don't forget to turn it off (maybe having tsconfig.prod file) when you will build your production bundle, because source maps will increase your bundle size